# Automatically run a macro when computer is turned on

Tags: vba, automation

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically run a macro as soon as I turn on the computer.

I know the `Sub Auto_Open` which allows to run the macro as soon as I open Excel, but is there a way to run the macro when I turn on the computer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not finding a way to automatically run your macro, but you can just go to "Task Scheduler" and create task to schedule it to open excel as on log on.

[how to scheduling task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721931(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another option - create a bat file, openning Excel. Run the bat file, once windows starts.

Depending on what you want to do with the macro, it can be that you only have to create the bat file. This seems like a good tutorial : http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/